# Get value of submit button in `onSubmit` eventhandler in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms

Normally, when I have a form, I would react to the `onSubmit` handler

```
<form onSubmit={e => { ... } }>
   <input ... />
   <input ... />
   <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>
```

This pattern also plays well with e.g. formik, that has an `onSubmit` event handler - and if I place a `<button type="submit">` in the form, the formik event handler will be triggered.

However, I am now in a situtation where one of two things should happen, and the UI right now is to have two different submit buttons. (Is this a bad pattern?)

My thought was to put a value on the button, but I cannot figure out how to read the value from the event handler

```
<form onSubmit={e => {
       // how do I figure out which button was pressed
       const type = e. ???
    }}>
    <input ... />
    <input ... />
    <button type="submit" name="type" value="DO_THIS">Do This!</button>
    <button type="submit" name="type" value="DO_THAT">Do That!</button>
</form>
```

My solution right now is to have individual `onClick` handlers on the buttons, which works - but it annoys me.

Comment: From my understanding, in the react framework we should use an object to store the form data, and then use the `onchange` event handler to update the object field.

Comment: @TheKNVB That is correct - but when you react to onchange, and update the state - the new state is not available until the next rerender. Since I am reacting directly to the submit event, I don't get to wait to the next rerender. My model for a solution is inspired by the fact that values of submit buttons in old school form posts submit are posted like other fields. However, this answer suggests I shouldn't depend on multiple submit buttons anyway: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73369542/158483

Answer (score 0):

```js
handleInput(el) {
 console.log(el.target.value);
}
```

```html
<button type="submit" name="type" value="DO_THIS" onClick={this.handleInput} >Do This!</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving name and type to a button and catch it using window.event.submitter.name.

`
DO THIS

```
<button type="submit" name="DO_THAT">DO THAT</button> 

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit} > ...
const handleSubmit = () => { 
const buttonType=window.event.submitter.name; 

if(buttonType==="DO_THAT"){
//HANDLE DO_THAT FUNCTION
return;
}

if(buttonType==="DO_THIS"){
 //HANDLE DO_THIS FUNC
return;
}

}
```

`

Comment: While This May Answer This Question For Instance, Please Consider Adding A Better Explanation Of What The Code Exactly Does. Also Please Format Your Code To Make It Better Readable.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, in the react framework we should use an object to store the form data, and then use the `onchange` event handler to update the object field value. So, I give you an example for your reference.

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";
export default function App() {
  const [data, updateData] = useState({ field1: null, field2: null });
  let updateF1 = (e) => {
    let temp={...data}
    temp.field1=e.target.value;
    updateData(temp)
  };
  let updateF2 = (v) => {
    let temp={...data}
    temp.field2=v;
    updateData(temp);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <form>
        <input type="text" name="field1" onChange={updateF1} />
        <input type="button" onClick={() => updateF2("DO_THIS")} value="Do This!" />
        <input type="button" onClick={() => updateF2("DO_THAT")} value="Do That!" />
      </form>
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(data)}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Using 2 submit in the same form is a bad practice. Please avoid that.

You can have one type=submit and other buttons type=button.

```
<button type="submit" name="do_this" value="DO_THIS">Do This!</button>
<button type="button" name="do_that" value="DO_THAT" onClick="thatHandler()">Do That!</button>
```

for DO_THIS button you can continue using form submit handler as you have now.

for DO_THAT button you can have onClick with thatHandle function.

```
thatHandler() {
 // Your code goes here.
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing it it's a bad practice, which I half suspected. What about a form without _any_ submit button? Another problem is if the user presses the enter key, the "submit" button will be called implicitly, and we want the user to be explicit about which action to choose? So maybe none of them being a submit button is better? Or maybe it should be an option/radio or something where the user is forced to take into consideration which choice to choose.

Comment: You can use Form without submit type and button type="button". which avoid submit calls. also you can remove onSubmit handler in form as you use type="button".